# Karabiner Elements: Is it possible to make a complex modification that takes of of multiple keybindings, and presses keys based on the input

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I'd like a modification where I could press one of multiple keybinds, like CMD B or CMD I, and it outputs a specific key combination, like CMD A for example, and then outputs whichever keybind I pressed, like CMD B or CMD I depending on which one I pressed. Here's psuedocode:

```
from: CMD B or CMD I
to:
CMD A
input (from) keybind
```

I want to be able to add several possible inputs, and the modification presses CMD A first then one of them:

```
from: one of the following: CMD B, CMD I, CMD E, CMD D
to:
CMD A
input (from) keybind
```

Maybe I'd want to add specific keys anywhere in the to section:

```
from: one of the following: CMD B, CMD I, CMD E, CMD D
to:
CMD X
CMD A
CMD K
input (from) keybind
CMD G
```

I did lots of googling to see if this is possible but I couldn't figure it out.